# Composable view crashes loading HTTP request Kotlin jetpack compose retrofit

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit

I'm having trouble sending HTTP requests in Kotlin using Retrofit. The app crashes every time I try to load the composable function `SampleView()` shown below. I'm trying to send an HTTP request to a local Node.js API with the Kotlin code below. I'm not sure if it's all correct, or if there are any errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

SampleView:

```
@RequiresExtension(extension = Build.VERSION_CODES.S, version = 7)
@Composable
fun SampleView() {
    val data: ArrayOfSampleData = loadData()

    Text(text = data.data.str)
}

@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
@RequiresExtension(extension = Build.VERSION_CODES.S, version = 7)
fun loadData(): ArrayOfSampleData {
    var data: ArrayOfSampleData = (ArrayOfSampleData((SampleDataClass(id = 0, str = "", bools = arrayOf(0)))))

    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = try {
            RetrofitInstance.api.loadData()
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            print(e.message)
            return@launch
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            print(e.message)
            return@launch
        }

        if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                data = response.body()!!
            }
        }
    }

    return data
}
```

Retrofit configuration:

```
object RetrofitInstance {

    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        addInterceptor(Interceptor())
    }.build()

    val api : ApiInterface by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Util.Base)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }
}

class Interceptor: Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("apikey", "apikey")
            .build()

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}

interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/test")
    suspend fun loadData(): Response<ArrayOfSampleData>;
}

object Util {
    const val Base = "localhost:4300"
}
```

Data classes:

```
data class SampleDataClass(
    val id: Int,
    val str: String,
    val bools: Array<Int>
)

data class ArrayOfSampleData(
    val data: Array<SampleDataClass>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
@Composable
fun SampleView() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val data = remember { mutableStateOf<ArrayOfSampleData?>(null) }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        data.value = loadData(scope)
    }

    if (data.value != null) {
        // Update your UI here based on the loaded data
        Text(text = data.value!!.data.joinToString { it.str })
    } else {
        Text(text = "Loading...")
    }
}

suspend fun loadData(scope: CoroutineScope): ArrayOfSampleData? {
    var data: ArrayOfSampleData? = null
    scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = try {
            RetrofitInstance.api.loadData()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("HTTP Error", e.message ?: "An error occurred")
            null
        }
        if (response != null && response.isSuccessful) {
            data = response.body()
        }
    }.join() // Wait for the coroutine to complete
    return data
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).